# How do I skip documents that cant be parsed?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, lxml

That’s my code to parse the data:

```
def parse_html(box_score):
    with open(box_score, "rb") as f:
        html = f.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.over_header")]
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.thead")]
    return soup

def read_line_score(soup):
    line_score = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(soup)), attrs = {'id': 'line_score'})[0]
    cols = list(line_score.columns)
    cols[0] = "team"
    cols[-1] = "total"
    line_score.columns = cols

    line_score = line_score[["team", "total"]]

    return line_score
```

That’s the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\david\Desktop\NBA Predicter\parse_data.py", line 50, in <module>
    line_score = read_line_score(soup)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\david\Desktop\NBA Predicter\parse_data.py", line 23, in read_line_score
    line_score = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(soup)), attrs = {'id': 'line_score'})[0]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1245, in read_html
    return _parse(
           ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 988, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 248, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 814, in _build_doc
    raise XMLSyntaxError("no text parsed from document", 0, 0, 0)
  File "<string>", line 0
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: no text parsed from document
```

Is there a way to skip the documents that can’t be parsed or is there another solution to the problem?

<sub>I added not all of the code, because it didn’t let me do it. If you need more, I can add more.</sub>

Comment: You can catch the exception and return `None` instead.

Comment: Why is `parse_html` building two lists that are immediately discarded? List comprehensions are not "one-line for loops". If all you want to do is see if each call to `s.decompose` succeeds, use a regular for loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Indeed comment above, first fix unused comprehensions. Then when you post more code so we may see how you articulate these two functions, make it minimal as in [MRE]. For example if line `cols[0] = "team"` is not part of the problem, don't mention it here. If `parse_html(box_score)` isn't part of the problem, also skip it. If `line_score = pd.read_html(...` is the only issue, then why mention the rest? + do use first comment by @AndrejKesely